# about psd to html, only images?

Tags: html, psd

Why isn't it possible to convert a layered image (such as in Photoshop) to a good web page with maintainable code?

```
        <div id="2copy3"><img src="images/2copy3.png"></div>
        <div id="Layer24"><img src="images/Layer24.png"></div>
        <div id="Lines"><img src="images/Lines.png"></div>
        <div id="Shape1"><img src="images/Shape1.png"></div>
        <div id="Tab"><img src="images/Tab.png"></div>
        <div id="Home"><img src="images/Home.png"></div>
        <div id="LocationSouthAfrica"><img src="images/LocationSouthAfrica.png"></div>
        <div id="CrewDragna"><img src="images/CrewDragna.png"></div>
        <div id="Health100"><img src="images/Health100.png"></div>
        <div id="Points44080"><img src="images/Points44080.png"></div>
        <div id="Bullets28883"><img src="images/Bullets28883.png"></div>
        <div id="TableDesign"><img src="images/TableDesign.png"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to know why the authors of a particular product have designed it a certain way you should ask them. If it doesn't do what you want, use a different one. Posting unanswerable questions here isn't useful. This is off-topic.

Comment: @MikeW I interpret this question more generically.  "Why isn't it possible to convert a layered image (such as in Photoshop) to a good web page with maintainable code?"  Even in this case though, it would be more on-topic at SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a visual representation to a fully functioning web page that is well thought out for many devices is something that requires a human.  There is no algorithm (thus far, maybe in science fiction) that can make the appropriate decisions for *interpreting* a design and building a site out of it.

It's not just a conversion.  There is an art to this.  Unless of course you want a page that is just images...

Comment: how can i in the best way, trought looking at a psd, get the results i am looking on, to fit for my webpage coding wise?

Comment: @user3199857 Learn to build web pages, or hire someone who can.

Comment: i can myself, but im not used to psd files at all.